# how to display icon only when you are within the site using page action by url

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension page action that works on certain URLs, more I realized that the URL specifies the icon shows in situations like this www.google.com/urlespecifies, I want the icon to appear only when the User is within the site.

My background file is thus

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

if (~tab.url.indexOf('urlespecifies.com')) {
chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
}

});
```

my manifest

```
{
  "name": "Compra Protegida",
  "version": "1.6",
  "description": "Alerta usuários ao acessar sites de compras virtuais não recomendado pelo Reclame Aqui ou presentes na Lista do Procon. ",
  "background" :  { 
  "scripts" :  [ "background.js" ] 
} , 
  "page_action": {
  "default_icon": "19.png",
  "default_title":"Site não recomendado",
  "default_popup":"popup.html"
},
  "permissions" : [
     "tabs"
],
  "icons" : {
    "48" : "48.png",
    "128" : "128.png"
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you ask how to compare with urlespecifies.com? I modified your background.js to appear only within the specify site like this.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

if (tab.url.indexOf('urlespecifies.com') > -1) {
chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }

});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want the icon appears when the user is within the site eg urlespecifies.com, do not want to appear icon so www.google.com/urlespecifies.com/ can understand?

Comment: So what I understand is you want an exact match rather that to check whether the argument string is contained in the calling string. If that, you can use "localeCompare" or "===". Like: if(tab.url.localeCompare('http://www.urlespecifies.com/') == 0) or  if(tab.url === 'http://www.urlespecifies.com/')

Comment: I did with these two form but now the icon does not appear in the url

Comment: Does the two urls exactly match in these two forms?

Comment: No problem. It seems not hard to dubug on it.